# Laravel show client name in invoices list

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables: 'clients' and 'invoices'. Client model hasMany invoices, and Invoice model belongsTo a client, practically a one to many relationship, nothing special.

On client profile page, i displayed his invoices:

**ClientController.php**

```
public function show($id) {

    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

    $invoices = Client::find($id)->invoices;

    return view('clients/profile', compact('clients', 'invoices'));

}
```

In view, i have a loop who display all invoices data. Everyhing good! 
My problem is on invoices page. Invoices page have a scope: to display all invoices from all clients, but in invoices list to display client name. That's the thought part for me because i can't figured out how i select the name client from 'clients' table. In invoices table i have a row 'client_id'. 
For the moment i have this code:
**InvoiceController**

```
public function index() {

    $invoices = Invoice::all();
    $clients = Client::all();

    return view('invoices/list', compact('invoices', 'clients'));

}
```

and
**list.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
     {{ $invoice->number }}
     @foreach ($clients as $client)
          {{ $client->name }}??????????????
     @endforeach
     {{ $invoice->amount }}
@endforeach
```

Nothing display on $client->name. I don't know how to obtain every client name on his invoice because i need to display client name from 'clients' table, based on 'client_id' from 'invoices' table. Maybe I can do this with Eloquent....?!?

Comment: Define relationships in models, and then you can use : `$invoice->client->name`

Answer (score 0):

All you have one client for one invoice then,

Setup **client()** relationships in invoice model 
and then get the invoice with the client

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('client')->all();
```

After that in your blade file

```
@foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
     {{ $invoice->number }}
     {{ $invoice->client->name }}
     {{ $invoice->amount }}
@endforeach
```